# How to implement a data storage in local storage or in cookie set by users?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have three scripts through which a user can change CSS on a page by selecting a `.css` file:

```
<script>
function setStyle(css) {
  document.querySelector('link#style').href = css;
}
</script>
```

Changes the font size:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  //Минимальный размер шрифта
  var min=9;    

  //Максимальный размер шрифта
  var max=16;   

  //Сохраняем заданное в таблице стилей значение размера шрифта
  var reset = $('p').css('fontSize'); 

  //Изменение размера будет проводиться для указанных элементов
  var elm = $('p, h1, a, ul, li, div.sp-head, h2.widgettitle, label, h3.comment-reply-title, input.submit, span, h4.comments');  

  //Устанавливаем в переменной значение шрифта по умолчанию (удаляем px)
  var size = str_replace(reset, 'px', ''); 
  var size_reset = size;

  //Функция увеличения размера шрифта
  $('a.fontSizePlus').click(function() {

    //Если размер шрифта меньше или равен максимальному значению
    if (size<=max) {

      //Увеличиваем размер шрифта
      size++;

      //Устанавливаем размер шрифта
      elm.css({'fontSize' : size});
    }

    //Прерываем передачу события далее по дереву DOM
    return false;   

  });

  //Функция уменьшения размера шрифта
  $('a.fontSizeMinus').click(function() {

    //Если размер шрифта больше или равен минимальному значению
    if (size>=min) {

      //Уменьшаем размер
      size--;

      //Устанавливаем размер шрифта
      elm.css({'fontSize' : size});
    }

    //Прерываем дальнейшую передачу события по дереву DOM
    return false;   

  });

  //Функция сброса к значению по умолчанию
  $('a.fontReset').click(function () {

    //Устанавливаем значение размера шрифта по умолчанию
     size = size_reset;
     elm.css({'fontSize' : reset});     
  });

});

//Функция замена строки
function str_replace(haystack, needle, replacement) {
  var temp = haystack.split(needle);
  return temp.join(replacement);
}
</script>
```

Extends content page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('WideButton').onclick = function()
    {
        if(document.body.className != 'wide_class')
        {
            document.body.className = 'wide_class';
        }
        else
        {
            document.body.className = '';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Management is done through link elements:

```
<a href="#" class="fontSizePlus">A+</a> | <a href="#" class="fontSizeMinus">A-</a>
<a id="WideButton" name="WideButton">Wide mode</a>

<a onclick="setStyle('sitecom/wp-content/themes/theme1/style1.css')" href="#">style1</a> 
<a onclick="setStyle('sitecom/wp-content/themes/theme1/style2.css')" href="#">style2</a>
<a onclick="setStyle('sitecom/wp-content/themes/theme1/style3.css')" href="#">style3</a>
<a onclick="setStyle('sitecom/wp-content/themes/theme/style4.css')" href="#">style4</a>
```

The style itself is set in:

```
<link id="style" href="sitecom/wp-content/themes/theme1/style1.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

On the page, all of these changes work fine. But if you follow the link or refresh the page, everything goes astray. How to make changes to the site by the user stored in cookies or in local storage? So, that after reloading CSS the page properties do not get off?

Comment: you need to store a reference to the selected CSS file in your `click` function, save it to `localStorage` ( easiest syntax ) and on page load check for that item in localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `localstorage` api and store the user selected css styles in the form of a json when user is updating the styles. And in the `$(document).ready` u can check whether localstorage has any user selected style preferences then load those styles or else load default styles as your are currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

As example of how you might do this `style-switching` using `localStorage` rather than a `cookie` to remember the user preference I quickly hashed together a little demo.

`StoreFactory` is just a littler helper function I put together and use to simplify some of the workings of local/session storage ( though, tbh, it's pretty simple already. ) It appears to work OK in tests - you will need to modify from `console.info( data )` onwards to actually set the active stylesheet - I don't have stylesheets `1,2,3 and 4` available....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Stylesheet switcher</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='style' />
        <script>

            const StoreFactory=function( name, type ){
                'use strict';
                const engine = !type || type.toLowerCase() === 'local' ? localStorage : sessionStorage;

                const set=function( data ){
                    engine.setItem( name, JSON.stringify( data ) );
                };
                const get=function(){
                    return exists( name ) ? JSON.parse( engine.getItem( name ) ) : false;
                };
                const remove=function(){
                    engine.removeItem( name );
                };
                const exists=function(){
                    return engine.getItem( name )==null ? false : true;
                };
                const create=function(){
                    if( !exists() ) set( arguments[0] || {} );
                };
                return Object.freeze({
                    set,
                    get,
                    exists,
                    create,
                    remove
                });
            };




            let store;
            let sheet=document.querySelector('link#style');


            const setStyle=function( css ){
                store.create();
                store.set({css:css});
                sheet.href = css;
            };


            window.onload = function(){
                store=new StoreFactory( 'css', 'local' );
                if( store.exists() ){
                    let data=store.get();
                    console.info( data );

                    /* to call the stylesheet */
                    sheet.href=data.css;
                }
            };

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <a href="#" class="fontSizePlus">A+</a> | <a href="#" class="fontSizeMinus">A-</a>
        <a id="WideButton" name="WideButton">Wide mode</a>

        <a onclick="setStyle('sitecom/wp-content/themes/theme1/style1.css')" href="#">style1</a> 
        <a onclick="setStyle('sitecom/wp-content/themes/theme1/style2.css')" href="#">style2</a>
        <a onclick="setStyle('sitecom/wp-content/themes/theme1/style3.css')" href="#">style3</a>
        <a onclick="setStyle('sitecom/wp-content/themes/theme/style4.css')" href="#">style4</a>


    </body>
</html>
```

---

Working example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Stylesheet switcher</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='style' />
        <script>

            const StoreFactory=function( name, type ){
                'use strict';
                const engine = !type || type.toLowerCase() === 'local' ? localStorage : sessionStorage;

                const set=function( data ){
                    engine.setItem( name, JSON.stringify( data ) );
                };
                const get=function(){
                    return exists( name ) ? JSON.parse( engine.getItem( name ) ) : false;
                };
                const remove=function(){
                    engine.removeItem( name );
                };
                const exists=function(){
                    return engine.getItem( name )==null ? false : true;
                };
                const create=function(){
                    if( !exists() ) set( arguments[0] || {} );
                };
                return Object.freeze({
                    set,
                    get,
                    exists,
                    create,
                    remove
                });
            };




            let store;
            let sheet=document.querySelector('link#style');


            const setStyle=function( css ){
                store.create();
                store.set({css:css});
                sheet.href = css;
            };


            window.onload = function(){
                store=new StoreFactory( 'css', 'local' );
                if( store.exists() ){
                    let data=store.get();
                    console.info( data );

                    /* to call the stylesheet */
                    sheet.href=data.css;
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <a href="#" class="fontSizePlus">A+</a> | <a href="#" class="fontSizeMinus">A-</a>
        <a id="WideButton" name="WideButton">Wide mode</a>

        <a onclick="setStyle('style1.css')" href="#">style1</a> 
        <a onclick="setStyle('style2.css')" href="#">style2</a>
        <a onclick="setStyle('style3.css')" href="#">style3</a>
        <a onclick="setStyle('style4.css')" href="#">style4</a>


    </body>
</html>
```

The stylesheets used

```
/* style1.css */
body{background:red;color:white}

/* style2.css */
body{background:blue;color:white}

/* style2.css */
body{background:blue;color:white}

/* style4.css */
body{background:green;color:yellow}
```

Comment: Can you complete this task for a cash reward? If so, where can I write to you?

Comment: that's not really how `Stackoverflow` works - the above code should suffice - perhaps with minor tweaks

Comment: console does not find problems in the code, but the code does not work. This script breaks style switching.

Comment: also, its my email: hexjeans@gmail.com

Comment: I found a problem. Your script does not want to work with this script: <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('WideButton').onclick = function()
    {
        if(document.body.className != 'wide_class')
        {
            document.body.className = 'wide_class';
        }
        else
        {
            document.body.className = '';
        }
    }
}
</script>

Comment: Without "Extends content page:" your script is working. But I want to use "Extends content page" script too.

Comment: that should be very easy to incorporate into a working version. I'm now going to bed ~ it honestly doesn't look difficult so have a go.

Comment: and also, if you use your script, in the case "<link id="style" rel="stylesheet">" does not load the style (displaying a page without a style), and then it loads the style from localstorage
if I ask him a link to "<link id="style" href="https://sitecom/wp-content/themes/theme1/style1.css" rel="stylesheet">", then it set style1.css first, and then loads the style from localstorage. It looks like a flicker.

Comment: you can write me tomorrow